# Magento 2 Paypal Pro Sandbox

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I am using Magento 2.1.7 Enterprise. I am trying to configure the PayPal pro. In Magento 2 we have following fields configure

[image]

For User i add the Username of PayPal Sandbox account for Password the password field of the PayPal Sandbox account. One more thing in PayPal Sandbox i am using the Paypal Business **Pro** merchant account.

Now when i try to pay using a SandBox buyer(personal) account i am getting the following error

User authentication failed result_code is 1.

When i try to search on internet i found one of it's reason can be Test Mode is set Yes. So my question is if I use the PayPal pro then i can not use the SandBox and then what is a purpose of the Test Mode here?

Comment: have you set sandbox mode to YES?

Comment: Actually in the PayPal pro there is no Sandbox option.

Comment: than you can't use your sandbox credentials, you should go with live credentials hope that will helps you.

Comment: Seriously? No sandbox? Test with live credentials? Anyone trying temporarily changing www.paypal.com to sandbox.paypal.com in the vendor code ??